# Does JSch support PPK3 format for authentication

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

We are using JSch library (jsch-0.1.55.jar) to make connection with SFTP server (Bitvise).

We are using PPK2 private key format and it's working fine with mentioned SFTP server.
But when PPK3 private key format is used then it is not working with the same server.

Does JSch library (jsch-0.1.55.jar) supports PPK3 format?

Can someone please help with the article or any workaround to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

JSch does not support PPK3.

Nor does the [@mwiede's fork](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch).

---

But it's just a format of the private key. There's nothing preventing you from converting your key to the PPK2 format. The server cannot tell the difference.